# Getting a 'path' of a current XmlReader position

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

What I really like about `JsonReader` in Json.NET is that you always know the path of the current `JsonReader` position. For example, we have a json like this:

```
{
    "name" :
    {
        "first": "John",
        "last": "Smith"
    }
}
```

If we are standing or "John" element, `JsonReader.Path` would be "name.first"

Is there a way to achieve something similar with `XmlReader`? Maybe use XPath? For example, we have a xml like this:

```
<root>
    <name>
        <first>John/<first>
        <last>Smith</last>
    </name>
</root>
```

I want to get "/root/name/first" while standing on "John" and "/root/name/last" while standing on "Smith"

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if your XML isn't ridiculously huge you can always use `XDocument` which allows you to perform linq queries against your XML so you aren't stuck with forward-only reads.

Comment: @JNYRanger I was thinking about this, but my documents can be pretty large, so no luck here. Anyway, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 5):

It seems like there is no way to do this using standard .NET functionality, so I came up with my own class.

```
internal sealed class XmlReaderWrapperWithPath : IDisposable
{
    private const string DefaultPathSeparator = ".";

    private readonly Stack<string> _previousNames = new Stack<string>();
    private readonly XmlReader _reader;
    private readonly bool _ownsReader;

    public XmlReaderWrapperWithPath(XmlReader reader, bool ownsReader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
        }

        _ownsReader = ownsReader;
        _reader = reader;
        PathSeparator = DefaultPathSeparator;
    }

    public bool Read()
    {
        var lastDepth = Depth;
        var lastName = Name;

        if (!_reader.Read())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (Depth > lastDepth)
        {
            _previousNames.Push(lastName);
        }
        else if (Depth < lastDepth)
        {
            _previousNames.Pop();
        }

        return true;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _reader.Name;
        }
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _reader.Value;
        }
    }

    private int Depth
    {
        get
        {
            return _reader.Depth;
        }
    }

    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(PathSeparator, _previousNames.Reverse());
        }
    }

    public string PathSeparator { get; set; }

    #region IDisposable

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_ownsReader)
        {
            _reader.Dispose();
        }
    } 

    #endregion
}
```

Note that this class does not form XPath (so no paths for attributes), but this was enough for my needs. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -3):

I use `XmlDocument` and the `XmlNode` class to work with xml Data.
While standing on a Node is in this case you have the `XmlNode` in this case `x`. There is no such methode to get the path to the node. But this code do it.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<root>" +
                        "<name>" +
                            "<first>John</first>" +
                            "<last>Smith</last>" +
                        "</name>" +
                    "</root>");

        XmlNodeList liste = doc.FirstChild.SelectNodes("*/first");
        XmlNode x = liste[0];   //Some Node
        string path = "";
        while (!x.Name.Equals("document"))
        {
            path = x.Name + "\\" + path;
            x = x.ParentNode;
        }
```

Comment: The question explicitly cites `XmlReader`. Why? Who knows, but your solution will crash and burn with larger files.